# Why are wooden houses warmer than concrete ones in cold regions?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

Why are wooden houses warmer than concrete ones in cold regions?

I went looking for data and I saw that both have similar emissivity and similar conductivity. Thus I am confused. Moreover, the density of concrete is much larger than that of wood thus for the same volume concrete houses will require much more energy for the same temperature rise (I have taken their specific heats into consideration, but if I am wrong please point it out). Thus I am baffled by this question and wonder as engineers and physicists, how should we tackle this problem? Besides, can we assume steady state or not?

Comment: " for the same volume
structure concrete houses will require much
more energy for same temperature rise ".   Thus concrete will absorb much more heat from room to rise its temperature whereas wood will absorb less heat to rise to same temperature and keep room warm.

Comment: How do you figure that only the density dictates how much energy wood vs concrete requires to heat for the same temperature rise? Typically that is what the specific heat capacity of a material dictates; in that sense it is more useful to look at the thermal diffusivity $\alpha=\lambda/\rho c_p$ which so happens to be a combination of the conductivity, density and heat capacity. Can you estimate the thermal diffusivities of both materials?

Comment: I think concrete is better conductor of heat than wood. Wooden floor never gets much hot in summer while concrete floor burns.

Comment: Concrete, medium 0.4 -
0.7

Comment: Wood, oak : conductivity 0.17

Comment: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thermal-conductivity-d_429.html

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Arrange all your comments into an answer. That way it will look better.

Answer (score 3):

First let us consider your quote" for the same volume structure concrete
houses will require much more energy for
same temperature rise ". 
It, thus, tell that concrete will
absorb much more heat from room to rise its
temperature whereas wood will absorb less
heat to rise to same temperature and keep
room warm.

Then I thought concrete is better conductor of heat
than wood. Wooden floor never gets much hot
in summer while concrete floor burns.

On searching 
http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thermal-conductivity-d_429.html
I found
Concrete(medium) has thermal conductivity 0.4 - 0.7 
Wood, oak : has conductivity 0.17.
This tells you reffered some wrong data.

This should solve your problem, since when concrete is better conductor, it will conduct heat inside the room to outside.
And wooden house would be warmer.

Comment: the heat will be absorbed by the surrounding , and not from the inside, and as both wood and concrete absorb the heat , wood's temperature will rise faster w.r.t concrete.  and i think the problem is a bit more complicated as we will have to consider unsteady state ( i realized if we take steady state outside and inside temp will be same). thus i think we cannot solely look on conductivity only

Comment: @vara    heat will be absorbed from inside by the wall and passed to surrounding.    Since wood has less conductivity it won't pass heat to surrounding easily.

Comment: Steady state is not being discussed here as conduction is purely dynamic process.

Comment: oh i forgot surrounding would be at lower temperature , (silly me). but density wont affect the problem in any manner ?

Comment: Effect of density is already considered in conductivity of material.